# quartz integration with spring batch for single entry point

Tags: quartz-scheduler, spring-batch

I am new to both quartz and spring batch. Would like to ask whether is it possible to implement spring batch with quartz as the single entry point for starting, stopping and restarting jobs? Quartz and Spring batch have their own sets of tables for tracking the jobs. Will there be any issues by using quartz as the single entry point?

Comment: Would you like to schedule the execution of your spring batch jobs ?

Comment: executed that. Now considering restart and stop through Quartz as single entry point.